# matplotlib python list comprehensive?

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, charts, list-comprehension

I want to do a simple chart to show the total of all appointments profit per day. the result shows something like that
[image]
which is definitely not right.
I know that the issue is in my views.py list comprehensive but not sure how to fix it.. any help is appreciated

**models.py**

```
class Service(models.Model):
  service_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  service_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
  physician = models.ForeignKey('Physician', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  def __str__(self):
        return self.service_name

class Appointment(models.Model):
  appointment_date = models.DateField(null=True)
  appointment_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
  patient = models.ForeignKey('Patient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  reseptionist = models.ForeignKey('Reseptionist', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
  service = models.ForeignKey('Service', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  physician = models.ForeignKey('Physician', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**plots.py**

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import base64
from io import BytesIO

def get_graph():
  buffer = BytesIO()
  plt.savefig(buffer, format="png")
  buffer.seek(0)
  img = buffer.getvalue()
  g = base64.b64encode(img)
  g = g.decode("utf-8")
  buffer.close()
  return g


def line_plot(x, y):
  plt.figure(figsize=(4,4)) 
  plt.plot(x,y)
  return get_graph()
```

**views.py**

```
from .plots import line_plot
def index(request): 
    prices = Appointment.objects.all()
    revenue = [x.service.service_price for x in prices]
    
    day = [x.appointment_date for x in prices ]
    
    c = pie_plot(revenue,day)
    
    context = {'chart': c }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: hmm, think of `plt.plot` like a pen that you put down on the first `(x,y)` position drawing a line to one after the next up to the last in the order as they're listed in `x` and `y`... so my guess is that you maybe just want to order `revenue` and `day` by `day`? quickfix: `day,revenue = zip(*sorted(zip(day,revenue)))`, maybe better: just some asc selection in django?

Comment: tried your solution it changed the colors and reversed the output